# How to convert Option API to Composition API for function and this.$refs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to convert all Option API codes to Composition API codes because in this app, there are codes that use Option and there are codes that use Composition. I want to make them equal so I'll just go with Composition API.

The problem is that I don't really know how to convert onclick function, closest function, and this.$refs.variableName to Composition API.

Here is the Option API code that I'm trying to convert:

```
<script>
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';

export default {
    mounted() {
        // expand
        this.$refs.toggler.onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var target = this.closest('.card');
            var targetClass = 'card-expand';
            var targetTop = 40;

            if (document.body.classList.contains(targetClass) && target.classList.contains(targetClass)) {
                target.removeAttribute('style');
                target.classList.remove(targetClass);
                document.body.classList.remove(targetClass);
            } else {
                document.body.classList.add(targetClass);
                target.classList.add(targetClass);
            }

            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        };
        
        new Tooltip(this.$refs.toggler, {
            title: 'Expand / Compress',
            placement: 'bottom',
            trigger: 'hover',
            container: 'body'
        });
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="card-expand" ref="toggler" class="text-white text-opacity-50 text-decoration-none"><i class="bi bi-fullscreen"></i></a>
</template>
```

And here is what I've tried using Composition API:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';

    const toggler = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
        toggler.value.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var target = toggler.closest('.card');
            var targetClass = 'card-expand';
            var targetTop = 40;

            if (document.body.classList.contains(targetClass) && target.classList.contains(targetClass)) {
                target.removeAttribute('style');
                target.classList.remove(targetClass);
                document.body.classList.remove(targetClass);
            } else {
                document.body.classList.add(targetClass);
                target.classList.add(targetClass);
            }

            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        }

        new Tooltip(toggler.value, {
            title: 'Expand / Compress',
            placement: 'bottom',
            trigger: 'hover',
            container: 'body',
        });
    });
</script>

<template>
    <a href="#" class="text-white text-opacity-50 text-decoration-none" data-toggle="card-expand" ref="toggler">
        <i class="bi bi-fullscreen"></i>
    </a>
</template>
```

The problem is that I still got 3 errors. The first one was from this code: `toggler.value.onclick`

The error I got was: `'toggler.value' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)`

The second one was from this code: `toggler.closest('.card')`

The error I got was: `Property 'closest' does not exist on type 'Ref<null>'.ts(2339)`

And lastly was from this code: `toggler.value`

The error I got was: `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Element'.ts(2345)`

Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: `const toggler = ref<HTMLElement>(null!);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';

    const toggler = ref<HTMLElement>();
    
    function doToggle(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var target = toggler.value.closest('.card');
            var targetClass = 'card-expand';
            var targetTop = 40;

            if (document.body.classList.contains(targetClass) && target.classList.contains(targetClass)) {
                target.removeAttribute('style');
                target.classList.remove(targetClass);
                document.body.classList.remove(targetClass);
            } else {
                document.body.classList.add(targetClass);
                target.classList.add(targetClass);
            }

            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));        
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        new Tooltip(toggler.value, {
            title: 'Expand / Compress',
            placement: 'bottom',
            trigger: 'hover',
            container: 'body',
        });
    });
</script>

<template>
    <a href="#" class="text-white text-opacity-50 text-decoration-none" data-toggle="card-expand" ref="toggler" @click="doToggle">
        <i class="bi bi-fullscreen"></i>
    </a>
</template>
```